# Using Terraform to load a single file from git repo

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-parameter-store

We want to load a file from a git repo and place it into a parameter store.  The file contains configuration data that is custom to each of several organizational-accounts, which are being constructed with Terraform and are otherwise identical.  The data will be stored in [AWS SM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).
For [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter) the Terraform code to store a string as a parameter is:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "parameter_config" {
  name  = "config_object"
  type  = "String"
  value = "long json string with configuration data"
}
```

I know there is a `file()` operator ([reference](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/file)) from Terraform and I know that TF can load files from remote git repos, but I'm not sure if I can bring all this together.

Comment: You could try using the data source for reading a single file from the GitHub repo: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/data-sources/repository_file. You would then reference it in the `value` argument, something like `value = data.github_repository_file.config.content`.

Comment: Git itself does not have a method for obtaining a single file from a Git repository. Many *hosting sites*, however, give you a way to do that. Failing that, a lot of hosting sites let you run `git archive` to obtain a single *commit* (perhaps reduced to specific files within that commit) as a tar or zip *archive*, from which you can then extract the file(s) you want. But if you're on GitHub, use the GitHub file-retrieval system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can do this.

The first would be to use the [`github`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github) provider with the [`github_repository_file`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/data-sources/repository_file) data source:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source = "integrations/github"
      version = "5.12.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "github" {
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  owner = "org-name"
}

data "github_repository_file" "config" {
  repository          = "my-repo"
  branch              = "master"
  file                = "config-file"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "parameter_config" {
  name  = "config_object"
  type  = "String"
  value = data.github_repository_file.config.content
}
```

You could also do this with the [`http`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/data-sources/repository_file) provider:

```
data "http" "config" {
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my-org/my-repo/master/config-file"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "parameter_config" {
  name  = "config_object"
  type  = "String"
  value = data.http.config.response_body
}
```

Keep in mind that you may get multiline string delimiters when using the `http` data source method. (e.g.: `<<EOT ... EOT`)

Comment: is it possible to use for each on the content ?

Comment: @DeekshithAnand depending on the file format, yes, you could. For example, if it were YAML or JSON. It would need to be a file format that can be translated into a map or key-value pair.